# Would this script work in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell, kernel

```
kernel=`uname -s`        # Current Kernel name
user=`whoami`            # Current Unix username
time=`date +%H:%M`       # Output current time
current_dir=$(pwd)       # Shell's current location
script_dir=$(dirname $0) # This script's current location

# This if statement is to know the correct location of the script, if the
# shell's location is the same as the script's location
if [ $script_dir = '.' ]; then
    script_dir="$current_dir"
fi

if [ $kernel == 'Linux' ]; then
    # Making symlinks to Vim files, add yours as you need
    echo 'Making symlinks to Vim files'
    ln -s -v $script_dir/vim /home/$user/.vim
    ln -s -v $script_dir/vim/vimrc /home/$user/.vimrc
    ln -s -v $script_dir/vim/gvimrc /home/$user/.gvimrc
    echo "Done at [$time]...\n"

    # Making symlinks to Zsh files, add yours as you need
    echo 'Making symlinks to Zsh files'
    ln -s -v $script_dir/zsh /home/$user/.zsh
    ln -s -v $script_dir/zsh/zshrc /home/$user/.zshrc
    echo "Done at [$time]...\n"

    # Making symlinks to Git files, add yours as you need
    echo 'Making symlinks to Git files'
    ln -s -v $script_dir/git/gitconfig /home/$user/.gitconfig
    ln -s -v $script_dir/git/gitmessage.txt /home/$user/.gitmessage.txt
    echo "Done at [$time]...\n"
fi
```

Would this work with no problems in Linux? I'm trying to make a `make_symlinks.sh` file, so I gotta check for Darwin (which already works), but since I don't have a Linux machine to test with, I don't know if this script would work in Linux.

So, does this work? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Wow, is it really that hard to examine it and tell me if it would work or not? Why the dislikes? At least show me where I went wrong. I'm asking the people that have Linux and know what they're talking about, of course.

Comment: We're not here to remotely test your code for you. Get access to a linux box and try it out.

Comment: I'm on a Mac, last time I tried installing Ubuntu I couldn't access internet. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A modified version of your script gives:

```
kernel=Linux
user=david
time=23:04
current_dir=/home/david/SO/Test
script_dir=/home/david/SO/Test
```

**modified script:**

```
kernel=`uname -s`        # Current Kernel name
user=`whoami`            # Current Unix username
time=`date +%H:%M`       # Output current time
current_dir=$(pwd)       # Shell's current location
script_dir=$(dirname $0) # This script's current location

# This if statement is to know the correct location of the script, if     the
# shell's location is the same as the script's location
if [ $script_dir = '.' ]; then
    script_dir="$current_dir"
fi

if [ $kernel == 'Linux' ]; then
  echo "kernel=$kernel" 
  echo "user=$user" 
  echo "time=$time"
  echo "current_dir=$current_dir" 
  echo "script_dir=$script_dir" 
fi
```

Your `ln` commands would work:

```
NAME
       ln - make links between files

SYNOPSIS
       ln [OPTION]... [-T] TARGET LINK_NAME   (1st form)
       ln [OPTION]... TARGET                  (2nd form)
       ln [OPTION]... TARGET... DIRECTORY     (3rd form)
       ln [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY TARGET...  (4th form)
#[...]
       -s, --symbolic
              make symbolic links instead of hard links

       -v, --verbose
              print name of each linked file
```

Comment: Excellent, this is what I needed to know. So, this would generate the correct symlinks to the correct places correct? You can exchange it for your own dotfiles' locations, to test it I mean.

Comment: Excellent! And just to confirm, those are the correct file names in Linux right?

Comment: @Eduan, the names of your dotfile seem OK. I see no reason for them to have different names between Darwin and Linux.